# Get a list of children of `md-list-item`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I have an `md-list-item` which is an `ng-repeat` and I want to get a list of children of it and invoke on the first one on the array index 0 a click?

```
<md-list-item class="selection-list-item" ng-repeat="site in siteSelectionController.sites | filter:siteSelectionController.fuzzySearchValue | orderBy:'id'">
 <div flex layout="row" layout-align="space-between center" ng-click="siteSelectionController.selectASite(site, true)" md-ink-ripple="true" layout-wrap>
   <span>{{ site.id }}</span>
 </div>
 <md-divider ng-if="!$last"></md-divider>
</md-list-item>
```

I tried to give an id for inner div, but as its a `ng-repeat` it wont work, meaning that the `id` of `'selectedSiteItem'` won't be unique, if I do a query on that, I will get back a list, not 1 element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index for id ,

```
<div id="{{$index}}">
```

and each time , new index will be present. You can even concatenate like

```
<div id="site{{$index}}">
```